# How to change a specific character in a text document with python?

Tags: python

I have a text doc in which I want to change a specific character "d" from every word it appears in the doc and i want to do it with python . I am using python 3 . Thank you. Here is my code :

```
import os
def main():
    f = open("hello.txt", "a+")

    # I am stuck here in my code in how to change "d" character from the document opened
    f.close()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How is your code related to the question?  How is the question related to the tag "operating-system"?  What do you want to change "d" into?

Comment: Sorry @DarrylG I made some changes to the post to make it more understandable. Btw thanks for replying.

Comment: try this: read the text of your document, change every occurrence of `"d"`, then write back out to the document again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question, it seems like you want to edit your hello.text file and
that .txt contains some character('d) and you want to replace it with any string.
So you can do something like this,

```
# Read in the file
with open('hello.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('d', 'abcd')

# Write the file out again
with open('hello.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: your code works but it adds to the string i.e instead of changing the character "d" it adds abc in front of it.

Comment: @Dev instead of  'abcd' you can put anything whatever you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

There u go. (try to understand what I did - it's easy - comment if u didn't get any of that..)

```
def main():
    with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
        fileData = f.read()
        print(fileData)

    a = [char for char in fileData]

    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == 'd':
            a[i] = 'LoL'
        else:
            continue

    with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(''.join(a))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I got it ! But will this code change the character "d" from every word it appears in ?

Comment: Yes, it will. try it now and let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: If you propose an answer to a question, how about _you_ check if your code actually solves the problem before posting? Like ... test it? Because, yours ... does not.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but--`char = 'LoL'` does not change fileData for two reasons.  1.  Reassigning to the iterator just reassigns the iterator.  2.  fileData is a string so is immutable.

Comment: @PatrickArtner My bad. I actually wrote that answer with the on screen keyboard (my physical kboard doesn't work good) - so I wasn't able to test the code.

{But still that was my fault} - Thank you for pointing that out. 
and I'm actually quite new in writing answers on StackOverflow (this was my 3rd ans overall). 
Again appreciate your response :)

Comment: @DarrylG

Yeah exactly, I missed out on that part and didn't take that into account when I was writing the answer (I hv no idea why). But thank You for the insight :)

Comment: @PSSolanki--no problem. Assigning to iterator in expectation of updating a value is a popular Python mistake.  From working with other languages, it's probably  Pavlovian to think to diddle with the iterator when updating values in a loop, but invariably doesn't work in Python.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense :)